# Passing data from tableviewcontroller to view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have six labels in my table view controller that all have the same id, however they have different tags. Once I click a cell, I would like to pass the value of each label (float values) into the next view controller activity. I am not sure how to go about this, and what to declare in the .h file and the .m file to make it work. Here is the code from the .m `tableviewcontroller` file.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NodeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label;
    Node *node = [self.nodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = node.nodeid;
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f", node.lastdelivered1.floatValue];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f", node.lastdelivered2.floatValue];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f", node.lastdelivered3.floatValue];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f", node.lastdelivered4.floatValue];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:6];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f", node.lastdelivered5.floatValue];
    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:7];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f", node.lastdelivered6.floatValue];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What have you *tried* so far? There is **plenty** of pre-existing literature out there to help you try and solve this problem.

Comment: I have tried creating a new instance of the labels, but it didnt work

Comment: for anyone wanting to answer the question, Im trying to pass data that specifically lies in the table cell into the view controller, that is what I am having trouble with

Comment: First of all, you must call `viewWithTag:` method on the `contentView` of your cell, because your label is subView of contentView, but not of cell. So, call `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:...];` instead of `cell viewWithTag:...];`

Comment: ok thanks, so can I call that method in the uiviewcontroller which I am trying to pass the data to

Comment: @AkhilYeleswarapu nice of you to accuse me of stealing code when all I m trying to do is help you out

Comment: @meda look man Im sorry I had a rough morning, and once I sent it to you you didnt respond for an hour and that has happened before where the person took it and didnt help. Im very sorry and I apologize, I was only quick to accuse because I don't know you. But Id still love to get help if you accept the apology

Comment: @meda I hope you can accept the apology, since this is the internet I was suspicious but it was nothing personal. I was just worried since you didnt respond for a while

Comment: @meda were you able to work on it yet?

Comment: @meda I thought you were going to help...

Comment: @AkhilYeleswarapu I am, the problem is I could not run the project, I got multiple errors. and project files and reskit missing. I wish you gave a little sample project with just that tableView Piece.

Answer (score 0):

in .m tableviewcontroller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Controller *myController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerIdentifer"];
    myController.node = [self.nodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self presentViewController:myController animated:YES completion:Nil];
    //or [self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES]; if Navigation Controller use
}
```

in .h file your controller that receive node

```
@interface Controller : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) Node *node;
@end
```

Comment: thanks, however instead of receiving the actual node array, can I pass each labels value instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070874/how-can-i-distinguish-which-part-of-uitableviewcell-has-been-clicked

Answer (score 0):

Try to save all labels text in to `NSArray *labelsArr`, and in header of you next ViewController add new property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *savedArr;
```

then in you didSelectRowAtIndexPath transmit you arr to other

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Controller *myController = [[Controller alloc] init];
    myController.savedArr = labelsArr;
    // here call you VC ass you want;
}
```

but if you use `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`
i advice you to do `myController.savedArr = labelsArr;` there.

Don't forget to put you labels text from array to place where you want in `viewDidLoad`, or `viewWillAppear`.

such way you can pass text to other labels, but ass for me using array is better.

Comment: instead of that, I am getting the text from each label and converting it into an integer. From there, how can I pass the integer to the next viewcontroller

Comment: @AkhilYeleswarapu save to array int value, [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[label.text intValue], [label2.text intValue],..., nil];