# UITableViewCell mask selection zone/size of selection area?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Is there a way you can mask an area on a custom table view cell so that if you press in the area you don't accidentally select the cell? Below is my tableview I will explain further what it is I am trying to achieve!

[image: My tableviewcell]

As you can see my tableviewcell is grey and has a dark grey section that I would like to mask, so that in the event that the user taps on said "masked zone" it doesnt highlight or select the cell that it is apart of. The grey area is just a standard View and has no special properties. With this in mind is there a way I can have the view act as some sort of mask or seperate zone on the UITableViewCell?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your cell class,

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if yourViewToIgnore.point(inside: point, with: event) {
        return nil
    }

    return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
}
```

This will ignore the touch on the specific view.

And then you have to customize the selection highlight after setting `cell.selectionStyle = .none`

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIGestureRecognizer to determine which part of the cell has been pressed. There's more on that on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11071214/5858330

Hope it helps!